# Alarming sound for indicator symbols on the instrument cluster on Hyundai i30

Tags: hyundai, handbrake, alarm

So, I recently bought a Hyundai i30 2014 model, the car works flawlessly except that I don't hear an Alarming sound for indicator symbols on the instrument cluster. For instance Alarm to pull down the hand brake, not wearing the seat belt, etc. I was wondering if this was somehow disabled by the previous owner and if there's a way I can enable it again. Many a times, I ran my car with hand brakes on as I didn't pay attention to the instrument cluster board, if there would be an alarm for that, it would really help.

Comment: So what happens if the oil warning light comes on? would you see that?

Comment: Haven't faced a situation where engine oil is low, so can't really comment what happens then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There can be multiple explanations for this:

**1.** Disabled the speaker through OBD port (some manufactures give you an option to disable this in the software using a laptop connected to your OBD port). This can only be done with special software and hardware.

**2.** Unplugged/removed the physical speaker under the dashboard.(This happened to my car, they just cut the wires and pulled the speaker)

**3.** Broken wire to the speaker making it so it can't generate a sound.

If you are handy enough you can either search the internet or the manual to find the location of the speaker and troubleshoot it from there.

Comment: thanks ill try to figure out what might be causing this.

Comment: @Spaniard89 Let me know what you find out. Ofcourse there are more options then i explained above but its a start.